# Simplify the complex if statements in java

Tags: java, if-statement

Is there a way to simplyfy the below code, I can combine condition1 and condition2 but I want the else statements print different messages for each step.

```
if(condition1){
    if(condition2){
        if(condition3){
            //do something
        }
    }
    else{
       //sout condition2 failed
    }
}
else{
    //sout condition1 failed
}
```

Comment: combine condition2 and condition3

Answer (score 2):

the simplest i could come up with is

```
if(condition1 && condition2 && condition3){
    //do something
}
else if(!condition1){
    //sout condition1 failed
}
else if(!condition2){
    //sout condition2 failed
}
```

Comment: That is not the same logic as question code. If both `condition1` and `condition2` are false, question code will do `sout condition1 failed`, but this code will do `sout condition2 failed`

Comment: OP edited Q., his initial Q. corresponds to this answer therefore it is/was correct. Mischiefz might update his answer to correspond to OP new reqs and code edition. @Andreas

Comment: @MS90 Then question must have been updated before this answer was even submitted, because question doesn't have an edit history, which only happens if edited in the first 5 minutes, and this answer was submitted 8 minutes after the question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to flip conditions 1 and 2, so it becomes an `if-elseif` construct, which doesn't require deeply nested blocks:

```
if (! condition1) {
    //sout condition1 failed
} else if (! condition2) {
    //sout condition2 failed
} else if (condition3) {
    //do something
}
```

If you also wanted `else` block for `condition3` (missing in question code), flip condition 3 too.

```
if (! condition1) {
    //sout condition1 failed
} else if (! condition2) {
    //sout condition2 failed
} else if (! condition3) {
    //sout condition3 failed
} else {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

merge condition 2 and 3

```
if(condition1){
    if(condition2 && condition3){
       //do something
    }
    else if (!condition2){
       //sout condition2 failed
    }
}
else {
    //sout condition1 failed
}
```

You can also check the false condition first like

```
if(!condition1){

    //sout condition1 failed

} else if(!condition2){

    //sout condition2 failed

} else if(condition3){
  //do something
}
```

Comment: That is not the same logic as question code. If condition 1 and 2 are true and condition 3 is false, question code will do *nothing*, but first block here will do `sout condition2 failed` and second block will do `do something`

Comment: yeah sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

```
if(condition1 && condition2 && condition3){
    //do something
 }

 String failed = !condition1? "condition1 failed":
                 !condition2? "condition2 failed" : "";

 System.out.println(failed);
```